# Regular Expressions - how to preserve original string while also replacing a particular pattern in a string?

Tags: regex, pcre

In context of PCRE, say if a given input string is as follows:

```
peakOfPeaks(nmax)
```

Now, I have regex as `(\p{P})` and my replacement string is  `_$1_` so that the output becomes:

```
peakOfPeaks_(_nmax_)_
```

How can I change the regular expression so that I can preserve the original string as well so that my output is:

```
 peakOfPeaks(nmax) peakOfPeaks_(_nmax_)_
```

Comment: `s + regex.replace(s, pattern)`? You may only refer to what you matched in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/naJJv1/1) using capture groups?

Comment: What is `\p{P}`? I can't find any documentation on that

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - yes that is very simple solution and I wish I had control over the string programatically. Unfortunately, in my case, I can only manipulate the string with regex.It is not a program but a configuration setting where I can only play with regex.

Comment: Then you are really stuck as it is not possible.

Comment: @Marathon55 you can find more info [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

A perl solution:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my $str = 'peakOfPeaks(nmax)';
$str =~  s/^(\P{P}+)(\p{P})(\P{P}+)(\p{P})$/$& $1_$2$3_$4_/;
say $str;
```

**Output:**

```
peakOfPeaks(nmax) peakOfPeaks_(nmax_)_
```